# Serilaizing in PHP returns wrong value

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I try to serialize my data with PHP. Unfortunaly, the serialize() function returns a wrong value.

String to be serialized:

```
{"2c4cfd9a340dd0dc88b5712c680c1f88":{"type":"product_custom","layout":"default","size":"medium_large","attributes":{"62d7d5184b7a313dc64255bdb8187847":{"type":"image","color":"#FFFFFF","image":"36018"}}}}
```

What serialize() returns on my server:

```
serialize($code);

s:204:"{"2c4cfd9a340dd0dc88b5712c680c1f88":{"type":"product_custom","layout":"default","size":"medium_large","attributes":{"62d7d5184b7a313dc64255bdb8187847":{"type":"image","color":"#FFFFFF","image":"36018"}}}}";
```

What should be returned (https://duzun.me/playground/serialize):

```
a:1:{s:32:"2c4cfd9a340dd0dc88b5712c680c1f88";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:14:"product_custom";s:6:"layout";s:7:"default";s:4:"size";s:12:"medium_large";s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:32:"62d7d5184b7a313dc64255bdb8187847";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"image";s:5:"color";s:7:"#FFFFFF";s:5:"image";s:5:"36018";}}}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what logic that site is using, but if you're just trying to serialize a string, you shouldn't expect the result to start with `a:`. **Edit:** it looks like it's decoding the string as JSON first - is that what you want?

Comment: I am trying to achieve a result like on this [site](https://duzun.me/playground/serialize). Unfortunaly im not sure how the site achieves the right result.

Comment: _"What should be returned"_ is the serilization of an array, not of a string.

Comment: So you could json_decode it first and then do the serialization. If you really need that.

Comment: Why are you serializing a JSON anyway - it's *already* a serialized object...

Comment: When i use json_decode, there are strange attributes like "stdClass"...

Comment: Because unfortunately this is the only way wordpress accepts it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it first to get the wanted result:
When you use the boolean switch as second parameter in json_decode it will be an array instead of an object.

```
$serialized = serialize(json_decode($inputString, true));
echo $serialized;

// output: 
// a:1:{s:32:"2c4cfd9a340dd0dc88b5712c680c1f88";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:14:"product_custom";s:6:"layout";s:7:"default";s:4:"size";s:12:"medium_large";s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:32:"62d7d5184b7a313dc64255bdb8187847";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"image";s:5:"color";s:7:"#FFFFFF";s:5:"image";s:5:"36018";}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The site you're using isn't clear about what it's doing, but it appears to be treating the string as JSON and decoding to an array before serializing it as PHP. If you want to replicate this, you can use:

```
$str = '{"2c4cfd9a340dd0dc88b5712c680c1f88":{"type":"product_custom","layout":"default","size":"medium_large","attributes":{"62d7d5184b7a313dc64255bdb8187847":{"type":"image","color":"#FFFFFF","image":"36018"}}}}';

echo serialize(json_decode($str, true));
```

> a:1:{s:32:"2c4cfd9a340dd0dc88b5712c680c1f88";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:14:"product_custom";s:6:"layout";s:7:"default";s:4:"size";s:12:"medium_large";s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:32:"62d7d5184b7a313dc64255bdb8187847";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"image";s:5:"color";s:7:"#FFFFFF";s:5:"image";s:5:"36018";}}}}

As pointed out in the comments, unless there's a specific reason you need serialized PHP, then just stick with the serialized JSON string you already have - it'll be both more readable and portable.